# Can a python function know when it's being called by a list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to make a python function that behaves differently when it's being called from a list comprehension:

```
def f():
    # this function returns False when called normally,
    # and True when called from a list comprehension
    pass

>>> f()
False
>>> [f() for _ in range(3)]
[True, True, True]
```

I tried looking at the inspect module, the dis module, and lib2to3's parser for something to make this trick work, but haven't found anything. There also might be a simple reason why this cannot exist, that I haven't thought of.

Comment: What would you want to use such a function for?

Comment: The generator would have to yield True instead of the value that it otherwise would. What about calling `list()`  over the iterable instead? Is that supposed to return Falses?

Comment: You *could* set a global variable that tracks the number of times its being called in a specific duration, if its lesser return False else True. But I cant conceive of any reason why you would even need this in the first place..?

Comment: Just add a parameter to the function that changes the behaviour as desired. Trying to be "clever" will just cause confusion for anyone who later has to try to understand your code.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve with this solution.

Comment: My instincts tell me that you have deeper problem which you've approached incorrectly and that's why this question has come up. What's the real problem?

Comment: I think your real problem is much more difficult than this, so you have to simplify it and ask this weird question?

Comment: Why can't people ask interesting questions without their deeper reason always being questioned.  It's a simple yes/no question about what you can do with the language.  Who cares what you want it _for_?

Comment: well in an academic sense you're right, @GreenAsJade, but as far as getting an actual problem solved, it's very useful to know what people are *actually* trying to do.

Comment: @GreenAsJade http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Sure - but here we have the "hypersensitive to xy problem problem".   This question is not "unclear because we don't know what problem it is trying to solve".  Actually this question is perfectly clear, and it is a yes/no question.   It is true that we don't know what problem this question solves, but that doesn't put it into the xy problem camp.  As it turns out, there is a creative answer to this question.  It's really interesting how it can be done.   The answerer warned that it's not good practice.  That's all good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can determine this by inspecting the stack frame in the following sort of way:

```
def f():
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except Exception as e:
        if e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_back.f_code.co_name == '<listcomp>':
            return True
```

Then:

```
>>> print(f())
None
>>> print([f() for x in range(10)])
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Its not to be recommended though.  Really, its not.

#### NOTE

As it stands this only detects list comprehensions as requested.  It will not detect the use of a generator.  For example:

```
>>> print(list(f() for x in range(10)))
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: for those interested, this seems to only work with python3, but yes this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Addon to my comment:

```
def f(lst=False):
    return True if lst else False

f() #False
[f(True) for _ in range(3)] # [True True True]
```

This would work, but is this the real problem that you're trying to solve? It seems a really unintuitive use-case which can be solved better by other means.

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation for the downvotes, instead of merely being trigger happy. We could all learn something this way. Thank you :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but suspect it's because your implementation doesn't match the spec :)   However, because there is no rationale for the spec, one could argue that this is a nice inventive solution!   So I upvoted instead!